# How to access a PHP array with keys of inner values

Tags: php, arrays

I got a PHP array which looks like that:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["Row"] => string(1) "1"
    ["Col"] => string(1) "1"
    ["Value"] => string(4) "lbl1"
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    ["Row"] => string(1) "2"
    ["Col"] => string(1) "1"
    ["Value"] => string(4) "lbl2"
  }
  [2] => array(3) {
    ["Row"] => string(1) "3"
    ["Col"] => string(1) "1"
    ["Value"] => string(4) "lbl3"
  }
}
```

I know that every pair "Row" and "Col" is different from the others. I can't change the way I'm creating the array.

Can I somehow access the array kinda like a hash table like this: `arr[Row => 0][Col => 0]` and get the value which is in Row 0 and Col 0?

Comment: Can you format your code as it was displayed with `var_dump()` with `XDebug` enabled?

Comment: Are you just trying to access single elements of the array?

Comment: @Rizier123 I want to access a single element that has a specific row and col I'm searching for. If for example there is an element with row 0 and col 0 get it and if not get null

Comment: Have you read the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php ?

Comment: I did but it doesn't contain the answer I'm looking for. I can't create the array differently and the way it's displayed in the question, that's how I get it.

Comment: @D4V1D is it better now?

Comment: Much better. Many thanks.

Comment: Cannot you reformat your array in order to have the `Row` and `Col` as inner keys for the `Value`?

Comment: @D4V1D That's what I'm not sure how to do and the reason I'm asking the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you would need to reformat you array in order to access it like so: `$array[1][1]` to get `Value` of `lbl1`.

Try this where `$array` is your initial `Array`.

```
<?php

$return = array();
foreach($array as $value)
    $return[$value['Row']][$value['Col']] = $value['Value'];    

var_dump($return[1][1]); // outputs "lbl1"
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant but close. I want to be able to reach "lbl1" if I try to access $return[1][1] since as you can see, the value of row and col in the array in the question are 1 and 1.

Comment: Right, I saw that. Working on that. Let you know :)

Comment: @YonatanNir Many thanks for accepting my post. Please also consider upvoting it as I upvoted your question as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need col and row as fields. Could you the key of the primary array as one? If it's a 2 dimensional array with just col/row, you should be able to create your array just use the keys properly.

```
$foo[1][1]="lbl1";

$foo[2][1]="lbl2";

$foo[3][1]="lbl3";
```

It's just as simple to access then, `$foo[1][1] returns "lbl1"`

Comment: I can't create the array I got differently. I get it the same way as it's displayed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)** to get the value:

```
<?php

$a = array(
  0 => array(
    "Row" => "1",
    "Col" => "1",
    "Value" => "A",
  ),
  1 => array(
    "Row" => "2",
    "Col" => "1",
    "Value" => "B",
  ),
  2 => array(
    "Row" => "3",
    "Col" => "1",
    "Value" => "C",
  )
);

$rowNeedle = 3;
$colNeedle = 1;
$result = null;

array_walk($a, function($row, $key) use($rowNeedle, $colNeedle, &$result) {
  if($row['Row'] == $rowNeedle && $row['Col'] == $colNeedle) $result = $row['Value'];
});

echo $result;
```

The code will return the last match in case the array contains more than one row with the same `Row` and `Col` value (though, as you said, that is not your case).